# IllegalStateException при парсинге json в RealmDatabase

Tags: java, android, json, realm-database

Использую базу данных Realm, есть следующий json объект который мне нужно распасить с файла и сохранить в базу данных.

```
  {
    "pPID": 1,
    "pName": "myName",
    "pDesc": "myDescription",
    "pTotal": 120,
    "pOrder": 1,
    "puoCompleted": false,
    "puoProgressPercent":0,
    "puoProgressCount":0,
    "pCommercialAccessRule": {
      "tag": "myTag",
      "contents": [
        "string object", "string object"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Проблема появляеться на объекте `pCommercialAccessRule`, в котором есть список строк. примитивные типы не поддерживаются, и для этого я создал объект

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject{

    String string;

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

И в классе `CommercialAccessRule` создал список не строк, а объектов `RealmString`

```
public class CommercialAccessRule extends RealmObject implements Serializable {


    private String tag;
    private RealmList<RealmString> contents;

    public CommercialAccessRule() {
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public RealmList<RealmString> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setContents(RealmList<RealmString> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

}
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
at android.util.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:310) at android.util.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:293)
at io.realm.RealmStringRealmProxy.createUsingJsonStream(RealmStringRealmProxy.java:136) at io.realm.CommercialAccessRuleRealmProxy.createUsingJsonStream(CommercialAccessRuleRealmProxy.java:390) at io.re    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRINGalm.PDataRealmProxy.createUsingJsonStream(PDataRealmProxy.java:525) at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.createUsingJsonStream(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:257) at io.realm.Realm.createAllFromJson(Realm.java:435)
```

Погуглив попал [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733024/gson-deserialization-of-liststring-into-realmlistrealmstring)  ,  а потом [сюда](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)  Но не могу понять как вписать это логику сюда:

```
  InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("test_pdata.json");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.createAllFromJson(PData.class, stream);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот клаcс `PData` json  которого я привел выше

```
public class PData extends RealmObject implements Serializable{

    private static final String TAG = PData.class.getSimpleName();

    private String pName;
    private String pDesc;
    private boolean puoCompleted;
    private int pPID;
    private int pTotal;
    private int pOrder;
    private  int puoProgressCount;
    private int puoProgressPercent;
    private CommercialAccessRule pCommercialAccessRule;
    private String originalJson;

    public PData() {
    }


    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setpName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public String getpDesc() {
        return pDesc;
    }

    public void setpDesc(String pDesc) {
        this.pDesc = pDesc;
    }

    public boolean ispuoCompleted() {
        return puoCompleted;
    }

    public void setpuoCompleted(boolean puoCompleted) {
        this.puoCompleted = puoCompleted;
    }

    public int getpPID() {
        return pPID;
    }

    public void setpPID(int pPID) {
        this.pPID = pPID;
    }

    public int getpTotal() {
        return pTotal;
    }

    public void setpTotal(int pTotal) {
        this.pTotal = pTotal;
    }

    public int getpOrder() {
        return pOrder;
    }

    public void setpOrder(int pOrder) {
        this.pOrder = pOrder;
    }

    public int getpuoProgressCount() {
        return puoProgressCount;
    }

    public void setpuoProgressCount(int puoProgressCount) {
        this.puoProgressCount = puoProgressCount;
    }

    public int getPuoProgressPercent() {
        return puoProgressPercent;
    }

    public void setPuoProgressPercent(int puoProgressPercent) {
        this.puoProgressPercent = puoProgressPercent;
    }

    public CommercialAccessRule getCommercialAccessRule() {
        return pCommercialAccessRule;
    }

    public void setpCommercialAccessRule(CommercialAccessRule pCommercialAccessRule) {
        this.pCommercialAccessRule = pCommercialAccessRule;
    }

    public String getOriginalJson() {
        return originalJson;
    }

    public void setOriginalJson(String originalJson) {
        this.originalJson = originalJson;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PData{" +
                "pName='" + pName + '\'' +
                ", pDesc='" + pDesc + '\'' +
                ", puoCompleted=" + puoCompleted +
                ", pPID=" + pPID +
                ", pTotal=" + pTotal +
                ", pOrder=" + pOrder +
                ", puoProgressCount=" + puoProgressCount +
                ", puoProgressPercent=" + puoProgressPercent +
                ", pCommercialAccessRule=" + pCommercialAccessRule +
                ", originalJson='" + originalJson + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```